# Issue with reading 2 csv file versions in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I have 2 csv files, I called them csvWorking.csv and csvNotworking.csv, they look the same, I checked with a comparing tool I found no differences. I using a PHP script to read the full file and show eadh row data with a pipe delimiter, my code is as following :

```
<?
$result = array();
        $row = 1;
        if (($handle = fopen(__DIR__.'/csvWorking.csv', "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                $data_row = array(
                    $data[0],
                    $data[1],
                    $data[2],
                    $data[3],
                    $data[4],
                    $data[5],
                    $data[6]
                 );                            
                $result[] = implode("|", $data_row);
                $row++;
            }
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($result);
        echo "</pre>";
        fclose($handle);
```

The result I get for the file "csvWorking.csv" is correct and as following :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Supplier ID|Legal Name|W9 Name|Email|Company Phone|W9 EIN|W9 SSN
    [1] => 10038|DS, Inc.|CR. H|candl4u@att.net|(626) 29951||5656321
    [2] => 10041|XRoa Inc.|St Kll|bokling@gmail.com|(602) 89101||329-6967
    [3] => 10042|Resngers LLC|Rescgers|rescgers85@yahoo.com|(540) 6-2073|244611|
    [4] => 10050|5-asing|5-dsing|joe7@gmail.com|(602) 993-4874|2738389|
    [5] => 10053|Apnds Server Inc.|Apands Serter Inc.|br@apachesands.com|(480) 98656|86-1398|
    [6] => 10055|Centu1 - Staddy |Joman|johman@johnoman.com|(860) 6-149||502-755
    [7] => 10060|Beines REALTORS, LLC|ElHines|betsnes@aol.com|(781) 837-06|2137602|
    [8] => 10061|Hampine es LLC|DAERGER|HF@gmail.com|(631) 2899||5-74-1043
    [9] => 10066|Cardeal Estate LLC|Careal Estate LLC|sheelby@nc.rr.com|(919) 77889|45-2440|
    [10] => 10067|LEAY ROADSIDE|leroadside|LEADIROE@YAHOO.COM|(214) 75791||896340
```

........................
........................
........................

but for the second file "csvNotWorking.csv" I get a wong result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Supplier ID|Legal Name|W9 Name|Email|Company Phone|W9 EIN|W9 SSN
10038
    [1] => |LEADIIDE@YAHOO.COM|(214) 7291||4566340
10074|J.LEN|LILTY GROUP INC
    [2] => 1) 66700||412340
10106|Centuc Homes|Marole|colrcia2000@yahoo.com|(860) 8-7864
    [3] =>  Wynn|KARL WYNN|KWN92@MSN.COM|(410) 721711||2211440
10132|Trianty Info, Inc.
    [4] => lty|Ma Cutis|malcolmcur@msn.com|(443) 384000||2240024
10154|Richard L Robinson
    [5] => nc|Homl Estate Inc|hometime@gmail.com|(503) 20117|20717|
10185|Shawna Matthews
    [6] =>  Gaett|sthen@mycomspan.com|(541) 40555||521864
10200|Keller Wiams alty Soern Oren|Chardet
    [7] => e Grodential AGroup ** ONLMAGE PROPERTIES NO VEHICLES ***|LaRiede|laa@riedegroup.com|(702) 84662|270709|
10221|Realtynals
)
```

The two csv files are attached down below.

[csvNotWorking.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/afl42cblsupr36b/csvNotWorking.csv)

[csvWorking.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5t3m4ew38pg67qt/csvWorking.CSV)

Can anyone tell me how to fix this to get the same result for both files please ?

Comment: Same code + same input + same execution environment = same result. Something must be changing. In any case why do you have 2 differently named files which contain the exact same content?

Comment: the first file is a file that I get by email from a company I don't know how they create the csv, the second one is the xls format that I convert to csv using excel, I see no differences I just want to know why my converted file works and the other not.

Comment: Those files are _not_ the same. `csvWorking` is a DOS format file (`\r\n` line endings) while the other is a unix format `\n` file

Comment: When you write the file with Excel, if there's an option for it, choose the WIN/DOS format then they should be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common problem when using these file functions is detecting line endings. Read here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings

You can turn on this option during runtime like so:

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',true);
```